# Django: How to pass nginx 405 error?

Tags: django, nginx

I delppoyed Django web application used nginx+gunicorn+supervisor.It works well. But when I try to add new post with picture in django admin I get a 405 error. On developer server worked fine.
My nginx config below:

```
upstream app_server {

  server unix:/tmp/PMC.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen   80;
    server_name site.ru;

    access_log /home/venv/PMC/logs/nginx-access.log main;
    error_log /home/venv/PMC/logs/nginx-error.log debug;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /home/venv/PMC/static/;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /home/venv/PMC/media/;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not certain this is an nginx issue. Is there a corresponding error in your nginx log? If so post that. If not, post the relevant code from your app, especially the view and URL router to the view for the URL your `POST` request is hitting.

Answer (score 1):

Error 405 is "Method not allowed", which means that either at Nginx level or using a view decorator you allowed only certain methods, i.e. only `GET` or `safe methods`, and probably not `POST`. Therefore when 'getting' the page it's ok, but when 'posting' it back you get 405 error.

Note: Nginx has special command `try_files` instead of `if(!-f ...)`. It's better to use it, as it offers much better performance and a little more secure.